# Woocommerce add products to cart

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

Is there a way to add a product to woocommerce cart without passing the product ID?
So I have a DB with products and I do not want to import these products to woocommerce products in backoffice. Can I add a product to cart without passing a woocommerce product with php or Javascript?

I am asking this because in order to show woocommerce payment options I need to have at least one product in the cart, or at least it seems to be like that...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a WooCommerce support question (they are best directed to the makers of WooCommerce). The technical answer (in general terms) is that PHP needs some sort of ID or handle to identify the thing you want it to do the stuff to. Also, I have no idea why you would expect a cart system to process transactions for things that are not within its system.

Comment: Me neither, I am just coding a previously built e-commerce website. I'd never do it with wordpress/woocommerce, it's just not made for developers (in my opinion ofc).
But thanks for your answer